# create new dataframes based on original dataframes columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with 10 columns, some of which are dtypes of object. `df` looks something like this:

```
 date          ID       Cat        Chan       Num
2021-04-02     abc     Chrome     Direct       8
2021-04-02     xyz     Safari     Search       5
2021-04-02     pqr     Firefox    Direct       6
2021-04-02     dcf     Chrome       NA         1
2021-04-03     abc     Safari     Search       3
2021-04-03     xyz     Safari     Search       4
2021-04-03     pqr     NA         Direct       7
2021-04-03     dcf     Chrome     Direct       5
```

what I need is to write a loop that first tracks only object dtypes in this df and and then create a new DataFrame for each column. These new `df`s should have columns heads for the values in the original `df` and rows to return count of each value per date. Something like this:

```
first new df: df_cat:
date           Chrome       Safari       Firefox      NA
2021-04-02       2             1            1          0
2021-04-03       1             2            0          1

Second new df: df_chan:
date           Direct       Search         NA
2021-04-02       2             1            1          
2021-04-03       2             2            0
```

Since column "Num" in original is int dtypes, I don't not want a new `df` for this column.

I tried something like the below but it gives an error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'item':

```
mylist = list(df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns)   
for item in mylist:
    category_item = pd.get_dummies(df.item)
    category_item.head()
```

Could someone please help me? I am not that good with Pandas, and it sounds like a big one for me to fix.

Answer (score 1):

You could `set_index` with "date"; then use `get_dummies` + `groupby` + `sum` on each of the object dtype columns to get the desired outcome.

```
df0 = df0.set_index('date').fillna('NA')
out = {col: pd.get_dummies(df0[col]).groupby(level=0).sum() for col in df0.select_dtypes(include=[object]).columns}
```

Output:

```
ID:
             abc  dcf  pqr  xyz
date                          
2021-04-02    1    1    1    1
2021-04-03    1    1    1    1 

Cat:
             Chrome  Firefox  NA  Safari
date                                   
2021-04-02       2        1   0       1
2021-04-03       1        0   1       2 

Chan:
             Direct  NA  Search
date                          
2021-04-02       2   1       1
2021-04-03       2   0       2
```

I used a dictionary here to map column names to the new DataFrames. You could store them in a list too.